# How to configure embedded Tomcat integrated with Spring to listen requests to multiple IP addresses?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm running my application with Spring boot with embedded Tomcat. There is few interfaces on my machine. Each interface has IPv4 and IPv6. I don't want Tomcat will listen to all IPs on all interfaces. I need it to listen only to IPs of one interface. How can I bind enbedded Tomcat with multiple IPs? Bind it to 1 IP is very simple (with `server.address` property in `application.properties` file).

But how to bind it to multiple IPs?

Or maybe there is even way to bind Tomcat to all IPs of specific interface?

**UPD**

Based on Martin Theiss answer I used such solution (ommited big amount of private fields and small help functions):

```
@Configuration
public class EmbeddedTomcatConfiguration {
//a list of private fields that I read from application.properties file

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> customize() {
        return factory -> {
            factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getCustomConnectors());
            //in getCustomConnectors() read all IP addresses of interface. 
            //For each of them except one create Connector and add all these connectors 
            //as additional Tomcat connectors. 
            //The last address save in private field defaultAddress and use it to configure factory.
            factory.setHttp2(getHttp2());
            factory.setAddress(defaultAddress);
            factory.setPort(getActualPort());
            factory.setSsl(getSsl());
        };
    }

    private Connector[] getCustomConnectors() {
        List<String> addresses = getAddressesFromInterfaceName(snefInterfaceName);
        if (null == addresses) {
            return null;
        }
        List<Connector> connectorList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String address : addresses) {
            Http2Protocol http2Protocol = new Http2Protocol();
            Http11NioProtocol protocol = new Http11NioProtocol();
            http2Protocol.setHttp11Protocol(protocol);
            Connector connector = new Connector(protocol);
            connector.getProtocolHandler().addUpgradeProtocol(http2Protocol);
            connector.setPort(getActualPort());
            connector.setProperty("address", address);
            connector.setScheme(Boolean.parseBoolean(serverSslEnabled) ? "https" : "http");
            connector.setSecure(Boolean.parseBoolean(serverSslEnabled));
            protocol.setSSLEnabled(Boolean.parseBoolean(serverSslEnabled));
            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(serverSslEnabled)) {
                protocol.setSslEnabledProtocols(serverSslProtocols);
                protocol.setKeystoreFile(serverSslKeyStore);
                protocol.setKeystorePass(serverSslKeyStorePassword);
                protocol.setKeystoreType(serverSslKeyStoreType);
                protocol.setKeyAlias(serverSslKeyAlias);
                protocol.setTruststoreFile(serverSslTrustStore);
                protocol.setTruststorePass(serverSslTrustStorePassword);
                protocol.setTruststoreType(serverSslTrustStoreType);
            }
            connectorList.add(connector);

        }
        return connectorList.toArray(new Connector[0]);
    }

    private List<String> getAddressesFromInterfaceName(String interfaceName) {
        if (interfaceName.equals(DEFAULT_VALUE)) {
            LogUtils.warn(thisClass, "Interface name wasn't resolved. Check \"snef-interface-name\" property in snef.properties file");
            return null;
        }
        List<String> result = null;
        InetAddress tempInetAddress = null;
        String tempInetAddressStringValue = null;
        try {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByName(interfaceName);
            if (null == networkInterface) {
                LogUtils.warn(thisClass, "Interface with name " + interfaceName + " is not found.");
                return null;
            }
            result = new ArrayList<>();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
            while (inetAddresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                tempInetAddress = inetAddresses.nextElement();
                tempInetAddressStringValue = getStringValueOfInetAddress(tempInetAddress);
                result.add(tempInetAddressStringValue);
            }
            if (result.isEmpty()) {
                LogUtils.warn(thisClass, "Provided interface " + interfaceName + " does not store any IP address");
                return null;
            }
            //remove last inetAddress to use it for TomcatServletWebServerFactory's default socket customization
            defaultAddress = tempInetAddress;
            result.remove(tempInetAddressStringValue);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            LogUtils.warn(thisClass, "Failed to read inetAddresses of NetworkInterface" + interfaceName, e);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory>` to add an additional connector.

If you do so, it is your duty to configure it accordingly (e.g. Protocol, port, address). See `org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeConnector(Connector)` how Spring Boot configures the default connector.

```java
package com.example.frontend;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class PrivateTomcatConnector extends Connector {
    public PrivateTomcatConnector() throws UnknownHostException {
        super();
        if (getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractProtocol<?>) {
            AbstractProtocol<?> ph = (AbstractProtocol<?>) getProtocolHandler();
            ph.setAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.2"));
            ph.setPort(5050);
        }
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> customizer() {
        return factory -> factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(PrivateTomcatConnector.this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. One more question: is there any way to bind Tomcat to interface? I mean, not manually bind to each IP one by one, but make it listen to all IPs of specific interface?

Comment: Not as far as I know. But you can get all addresses of an interface via `java.net.NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0").getInetAddresses()`

Comment: thanks, it works. But I still have 1 issue: I can configure port and IPs that I want to listen. But Tomcat still looking in application.properties `server.port` and `server.address`, listens to this port and IP, and IN ADDITION listens to connectors that I configured. I want Tomcat to listen ONLY to connectors that I configure. Is it possible?